# Raspberry Pi - Openelec - Buffering Issues

Tags: raspberry-pi, xbmc

I have installed openelec on the Pi, and I'm using an external hardrive (western digital 1tb elements, ac powered). It automatically mounts on boot. It plays all my standard movies perfectly, but when it comes to my blueray and hd movies (over 1.5gb), it starts to buffer every few minutes - which makes it impossible to watch.

Is this due to XMBC buffer cache? sorry I'm not really familiar with media centres and how they work, I'm setting it up for my kids.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Should be posted here: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

ssh to your RPi and have a look at `/storage/.xbmc/temp/xbmc.log`

You will see this line:

```
NOTICE: Contents of special://xbmc/system/advancedsettings.xml are...
```

followed by the default settings in use.

Then you can try playing with values of `cachemembuffersize` and `readbufferfactor`. For this create a file named `/storage/.xbmc/userdata/advancedsettings.xml` which contains the following:

```
<advancedsettings>
    <network>
        <buffermode>1</buffermode>
        <cachemembuffersize>20971520</cachemembuffersize>
        <readbufferfactor>1.5</readbufferfactor>
    </network>
</advancedsettings>
```